# Reconnect phpmyadmin to MySQL database using MAMP on pc environment

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mamp

I'm having common issue trying to reconnect PhpMyAdmin to MySQL DB. At the beginning everything works perfect and then after say 2 or 3 days working fine, for some unknown reason i get the error:

"mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server".

I'm using the same essential connection parameters in config.ini php file without any changes since the creation of the DB name and USER for HOST: 'localhost' / PORT: '3306' / USER: 'root' / PASS: 'root'

My system is Microsoft Windows 10 Pro edition 10.0.17763
MAMP for Windows 4.1.0.23876
PHP latest version 7.2.10
MySQL version 5.7.24

I have tried changing connection parameters in config.ini.php file located in PhpMyAdmin folder inside MAMP's bin directory, tried changing values like 'localhost' for '127.0.0.1' or 'config' for 'cookie' and also of course checked and reassured that the host, port, user and password are the same from phpinfo on MAMP but nothing seems to work.

```
 * First server
 */
$i++;
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
/* Select mysql if your server does not have mysqli */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '3306'; // MySQL port 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root'; // MySQL user
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'root'; // MySQL password
```

I expect MySQL server be able to reconnect phpMyAdmin somehow by fixing connection server parameters in the config.ini file or other file i'm surely unaware of without having to reinstall everything over again and so lose all wordpress site progress made so far

Comment: Welcome to SO! Those are not your real username and password I hope? I'm just paranoid because I just dealt with that on another question.

Comment: Hi Chipster! Thnx so much for your help!..i did not understand quite enough your question but yes! those are the same parameters i used when setting everything up. Can´t understand why connection issues show up when everything was set accordingly with the proper procedure

Comment: @Franko_P from the error message you're getting it looks like your MySQL server might not be running locally. I personally haven't used MAMP before, but there might be a place within the UI where you could probably restart the MySQL server it's supposed to be running.

Comment: Also @Franko_P, if you can confirm your MySQL server is running, make sure to check the port where it's running. I see from your PHP config that you're specifying port 3306, but you'd want to make sure that MAMP is actually running the MySQL server in that port. You should be able to see/modify this in the MAMP preferences.

Comment: Hey Luis! cheers & Thnx so much for your help...Yes! whenever starting the servers on MAMP the only one that starts running is the Apache server (green light on). MySQL Server stays off and doesn't start at all for it cannot authenticate the parameters hence, denies the connection.

Comment: ok... In MAMP preferences, the settings for Apache port is 80 and MySQL port is set to 3306

Comment: Oh I see, so there's actually a problem trying to run the MySQL server. The error message posted seems that is reported from PHPMyAdmin right? Which makes total sense since the MySQL server failed to run in the first place, and PHPMyAdmin won't be able to connect. Is there any other message that MAMP (not PHPMyAdmin) shows you? I'm just trying to figure out the reason why running the MySQL server fails, cause there can be plenty :)

Comment: @Franko_P looks like for Windows you could probably look at the files in `c:\MAMP\logs` to know more details about what could possibly be going wrong when starting the MySQL server

Comment: Yes, the error is reported only by phpMyAdmin and begins as "MySQL said: cannot connect - invalid settings". MAMP does not indicate any messages

Comment: ok C:\MAMP\logs contains 9 different files starting: access, apache_error, debug, mampapp, mamppro, mysql_error_log.err, php_error, phperror & temp...where should i check?

Comment: If you post your real username and password to your MySQL server, that can make you vulnerable to attacks. Just making sure you didn't do that, because you'd be surprised how many people would do that.

Comment: @Frank_P you will want to check the MySQL error log file.

Comment: @Chipster Well, i've set up simple parameters for HOST, USER and PASS momentarily while working locally on my machine until completing wp web project, i don't really see why there would be any attaks while working locally and testing using the wordpress. Certainly after finishing and upon uploading files to definitive external server i will change for secure passwords

Comment: @LuisCrespo Luis thx so much for your support! mysql_error_log.err file shows last 4 log attempt messages as follows: ` 2019-03-25T02:54:28.071688Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details) `

Comment: @LuisCrespo 2: ` 2019-03-25T02:54:28.071908Z 0 [Note] --secure-file-priv is set to NULL. Operations related to importing and exporting data are disabled `

Comment: @LuisCrespo 3: ` 2019-03-25T02:54:28.073806Z 0 [ERROR] Cannot open Windows EventLog; check privileges, or start server with --log_syslog=0 `

Comment: @LuisCrespo 4: ` 2019-03-25T02:54:28.073922Z 0 [Note] C:\MAMP\\bin\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 5.7.24-log) starting as process 9704 ...`

Comment: @Franko_P okay. Just checking. Like I said, I've seen people do that before, and just got a little paranoid.

Comment: @Franko_P Looks like there's a permission error trying to open the Windows EventLog when trying to run the MySQL server. Is there anyway you could start MAMP with admin privileges? It's been a while since I don't use Windows, but maybe there's something like "Right Click -> Run as Administrator"? That could probably help.

Comment: @Chipster i understand my friend. This is just the normal starting procedure whenever beggining to build any web project mostly rather than an app for example. Setting up a simple db given a user name with granted privileges and pass temporarily as "defaults" <<root>> for precisely guarantee no communication issues for the defaults root, localhost & 3306 are set by phpMyAdmin automatically. I have already made 3 uninstallations of MAMP due to this issue and need to know how to tackle it the right way for it does not happen again resulting in tremendous wp setback. Thnx so much :)

Comment: @LuisCrespo I definitively don´t know anymore at this point what could have happened. Same way, running MAMP as an admin (right click), the only server starting is the Apache one. MySQL server stays offline so the only left remedy seems to be complete reinstallation of MAMP. My doubt still is what to do when this happens again. Thnx so much friend :)